# Losing my mind on a simple seg fault caused by pthread_create()

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

In this code, I'm trying to create an array of threads. I've set the pthreads value to 1. In the for loop, the address, ID, and "created" gets printed, but the function never seems to execute as  I don't get a print.

The seg fault actually happens at pthread_join at the bottom, but it certainly has to be caused by the creation since the function never runs, right? producers[0] is the only thread since I'm just testing 1. The create function passes an (ID address, NULL, the void * function(), and void* arguments) like it's supposed to. It has to be something obvious but I've tried to figure it out for so long I'm empty.

```
typedef struct ThreadStruct {
    int threadIndex;

} ThreadStruct;


void *producer(void* ts){
    printf("in producer\n");
    FILE* inputfp = threadstruct->inputFiles[0];

    hostname = (char*)malloc((MAXNAME+1)*sizeof(char));
    while(fscanf(inputfp, hostname) > 0){
        printf("%s",hostname);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int pthreads = atoi(argv[1]); //always 1
    ThreadStruct threadstruct;
    pthread_t producers[pthreads];

    for(int i=0;i<pthreads;i++){

        printf("in pthread loop\n");
        printf("%p \n",&producers[i]);
        printf("%ld \n",producers[i]);
        pthread_create(&producers[i], NULL, producer, (void *) &threadstruct); 
    }
    pthread_join(producers[0], NULL);
}
```

Comment: This `int main(argc, argv[])` is typo or you wrote in that way ? It should be `int main(int argc,char *argv[])`

Comment: typo, I took out irrelevant code and retyped "main".

Comment: Why do you call pthread_join() only on the first thread and not on the other ones?  As it stands, your program may exit before all of the threads get to finish executing.

Comment: Also, all of your threads are receiving a pointer to the same ThreadStruct -- I can't imagine that is intentional.

Comment: i get pthreads from the command line, I've only set pthreads to 1 so far, so producers[0] is the only one that exists. I've intentionally given them all the same ThreadStruct because the assignment is to get us to work with race conditions, the ThreadStruct also has files that I have to work with but I took it out to focus on the errors here.

Comment: `printf("%ld \n",  producers[i]);` is problematic two ways:  (1) you're trying to print a `pthread_t` as if it was a `long int`, which it isn't, and (2) you're trying to print out uninitialized memory, since `pthread_create()` hasn't set `producers[i]` to a valid value yet.  Dunno if those could cause your crash, but once undefined behavior has been invoked, anything can happen.

Comment: The crash happens at pthread_join(); and I added the prints after I was getting seg faults to see what was going on.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work okay for me, here's an example of what I get:  `$ gcc -O3 ./temp.cpp`  `$ ./a.out 1
in pthread loop
0x7ffeeadc7640 
140732838737568 
in producer`

Comment: how about giving a `trace` or `dump`

Comment: Works ok here, but you need to check the result of pthread_create.

Comment: `fscanf(inputfp, hostname)` really?  you pass uninitialized buffer as the format string, I guess you meant `fscanf(inputfp, "%s", hostname)` (which is still a bad idea due to no buffer size check), or `fgets`. And check the return value

Comment: The code not complete. I guess the problem is in `producer`.   Please use debug tools to find out how many thread have created and the status of each thread. Gdb have command `info threads` show all threads.

Answer (score 0):

you don't seem to check *if the thread is actually created or not*, in other words you don't seem to validate the return type of `pthread_create` and straight calling `pthread_join` probably leading to *Undefined behavior*, in case `pthread_create` fails.

```
pthread_create(&producers[i], NULL, producer, (void *) &threadstruct);
```

from [pthread_join](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3p-pthread_join/)

```
   The pthread_join() function shall fail if:

   EINVAL The implementation has detected that the value specified by thread does not refer to a joinable thread.

   ESRCH  No thread could be found corresponding to that specified by the given thread ID.
```

however there are cases where  [pthread_join with invalid thread handle seg faults](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=102212).

a piece of extract from the link above

---

"*Passing invalid handle to pthread_join is like passing invalid pointer to a system call.

The implementation may detect it and signal it in errno, but it may crash as
well.

There are 2 different POSIX threads implementations on Red Hat Linux

- linuxthreads, where pthread_t handle is a small integer (and the number of
  threads is substantially limited)
- NPTL (the default, pthread_t is internally a pointer so that there are no
  arbitrary thread limits)

You can request the old-fashioned threading library with LD_ASSUME_KERNEL=2.4.19
in the environment.

For NPTL where pthread_t is a pointer, pthread_join detects some invalid
handles where it can be done cheaply. But detecting all possible invalid
handles would be very costly (the implementation would basically have to take
a global lock and iterate over all currently running threads, comparing the
handle with each of them. With say 100000 running threads you can see how
costly it is).

This testcase works on SuSE since SuSE only ships the old-fashioned non-scalable
linuxthreads implementation.*"

---

from [pthead_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)

```
RETURN VALUE
       On success, pthread_create() returns 0; on error, it returns an error number, and the contents of *thread are undefined.
```

perhaps something like this

```
if( pthread_create(&producers[i], NULL, producer, (void *) &threadstruct)  ) {
   perror("something wrong .. ");
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: How do I check? I created an if statement to see if it didn't return 0 upon creation, but it seemed to create.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in my side and would not produce the seg fault.
Here is the print out info:

```
$ ./pthread
in pthread loop
0xffffcb70
6444554784
in pthread loop
in producer
0xffffcb78
64
in pthread loop
in producer
0xffffcb80
1
in pthread loop
in producer
0xffffcb88
4299166064
in pthread loop
in producer
0xffffcb90
6443761969
in pthread loop
in producer
0xffffcb98
6445451520
in pthread loop
in producer
0xffffcba0
314761761601
in producer
exit main thread
```

Your code here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>

typedef struct ThreadStruct {
    int threadIndex;

} ThreadStruct;


void *producer(void* ts){
    printf("in producer\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int pthreads = 7;
    ThreadStruct threadstruct;
    pthread_t producers[pthreads];

    for(int i=0;i<pthreads;i++){

        printf("in pthread loop\n");
        printf("%p \n",&producers[i]);
        printf("%ld \n",producers[i]);
        pthread_create(&producers[i], NULL, producer, (void *) &threadstruct); 
    }
    pthread_join(producers[0], NULL);

    printf("exit main thread\n");
}
```

Comment: I just reduced my code to this, so I'm just going to work backwards and see where the seg fault happened

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check the return value of `pthread_create()` to check whether it was successful or not. For e.g

```
int ret = pthread_create(&producers[i], NULL, producer, (void *) &threadstruct);
if(ret) {
   fprintf(stderr, "failed to create thread %s\n",strerror(ret));
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

And Also it's advised to use `pthread_join()` for all the threads not only first thread, as if you want to wait for thread/s to terminate before further processing in main thread as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064640/do-i-have-to-pthread-join-each-thread-i-create). Also check the return value of `pthread_join()`.

Sample Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
typedef struct ThreadStruct {
        int threadIndex;
} ThreadStruct;
void *producer(void* ts){
        printf("in producer\n");
        return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        int pthreads = 5;
        int ret;
        ThreadStruct threadstruct;
        pthread_t producers[pthreads];
        /* create threads */
        for(intptr_t itr = 0;itr < pthreads; itr++){
                printf("in pthread loop\n");
                //printf("%p \n",&producers[itr]);
                //printf("%ld \n",producers[itr]);
                ret = pthread_create(&producers[itr], NULL, producer, (void *) &threadstruct);
                if (ret) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "failed to create thread #%ld - %s\n",(long)itr, strerror(ret));
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }
        /* join all threads */
        for(intptr_t itr = 0; itr < pthreads; itr++){
                printf("In main: joining thread #%ld\n", (long)itr);
                ret = pthread_join(producers[itr], NULL);
                if (ret) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "failed to join thread #%ld - %s\n",(long)itr, strerror(ret));
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }
        //pthread_exit();
        return 0;
}
```

it works in my system, hope it works for you also.

Comment: So, for some reason, no idea why, the seg fault happens within my producer() function AFTER the print, but before the print actually happens. I really don't understand but at least I've identified it.

Comment: The seg fault was from a while loop parsing a file. Totally unrelated to the code I gave you guys, I just don't understand why the print never printed because the while loop is way after my print in the producer()

Comment: Can't guess without seeing seg. fault causing code, code you mention in question is fine. Add the "while loop parsing a file" code in the question if you can.

Comment: @grilam14 you need to give a [mcve]  and avoid posting code that differs from what you have actually tried. I'm voting to close the question as off topic.

Comment: @grilam14 Here `threadstruct->inputFiles[0];`  I don't see `threadstruct` has  any member called `inputFiles`  in structure you defined ? If not, compiler could have thrown error. Also have you  checked return value of `fopen()`  ?

Comment: It was in the scanf, I have since fixed it but it detracts pretty far from the original purpose of this thread.